# Чёрный/мерцающий экран в Unity iOS приложении

Tags: c#, unity3d, ios, xcode

При создании билда Unity на iOS всё проходит хорошо. Однако, при запуске билда выводится чёрный экран с мерцанием изображения. Можно кликать на какие-нибудь кнопки, но видно, что скрипты, которые инициализируются в эдиторе, и на андроиде, тут не инициализированы. При создании билда для симулятора просто чёрный некликабельный экран

В проекте есть 2 SDK для аналитики, при этом ни в одном из них нет ошибок (кроме последствий, когда нажимаешь, например, на неициализированную из-за этой ошибки кнопку, и получаешь соответствующую ошибку). В логах я ничего подозрительного не нашёл, но [на всякий случай прикладываю в гугл доке](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_1gEEd_VmPxU6-JZF1hvDx-cXzLhz9_O2NeuEvpWKRE/edit?usp=sharing)

При запуске есть чёрная сцена, которая в последствии меняется на сцену главного меню. По логам видно, что сцена меню запускается, но почему-то тьма так и остаётся

Unity 2022.3.19. Xcode 15.2

Пробовал найти в приложении и Device Simulator-е. Добавлял try/catch выражения в множество блоков

Upd: Я также попробовал обновить юнити до 2022.3.21, добавить новый независимый канвас в сцену меню и добавить повторный запуск сцены меню через 20 секунд после первой загрузки. Это всё не помогло

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]